# Is there a way to get all objects that extend a prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been hunting for a way to get all objects that implement a particular prototype in Javascript.

What I am trying to accomplish is to auto-discover what's available at runtime.  I have a base Prototype, let's call it "Widget", that I intend to extend to make various types of Widgets.  I have found several sites discussing how one can implement a Java-esque [Reflections API in JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/object-reflection-in-javascript.html), and I had planned to use that to dynamically pull in the capabilities of the various Widgets.  The piece I am missing is the ability to say "Give me all the things that are `Widget`"

For show-and-tell portion, this is how I am defining my "Widget"

```
Widget = function(document) {
  if (document) {
    this._type = document.type;
    this._value = document.value;
  }
};
Widget.prototype = {
  get type() {
    return this._type;
  },
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  },
  set value(value) {
    this._value = value;
  },
  get someCustomWidgetMethod() {
    // Do something Widget-ish
  }
};
```

And an extension of the Widget:

```
MyWidget = function(document) {
  Widget.apply(this,arguments);
  this.type = "MyWidget";
  // Custom stuff here
};
MyWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype, {
  // MyWidget's prototype extensions
});
MyWidget.prototype.constructor = MyWidget;
```

Comment: Create a factory to create instances which enables you track all instances that are created? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Are you looking for instances created by `new ...()` or just the Constructors that have some special prototype?

Comment: @dsuckau Just the constructors that have a particular prototype.  Basically, I want to create a plugable object that I can read all the child objects at run-time.

Comment: @tiblu This would require me to have pre-knowledge of all the children objects, which I don't.  Otherwise I could have just made an Array of them.

Comment: You could create a simple inheritance function, your own "class system", that receives a base prototype, the new constructor and extensions for the prototype. That function would execute your second code example "Extension of the widget" with `Object.create()` etc.. But also you could save there some global inheritance information/registry about which constructor has which prototype etc..

Comment: @CodeChimp You mean You are not the one writing the Widget class and that is something that already exists?

Comment: Are you looking for subclasses of `Widget` only or really everything that inherits from your prototype (all instances)?

Comment: "Give me all the things that are Widget" from where? current scope?

Comment: this might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
var ClassSystem = {

    subClasses: [],

    getByBaseClass: function (baseClass) {
        return this.subClasses.filter(function (subClass) {
            return (subClass.prototype instanceof baseClass);
        });
    },

    extend: function (subClass, baseClass, config) {
        subClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass.prototype, config || {});
        subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
        this.subClasses.push(subClass);
        return subClass;
    }

};
```

Usage:

```
// Base Class
function Widget() {}
Widget.prototype.sayHello = function () {
  console.log('hello');
};

// Sub Class
function MyWidget() {}

// Inherit
ClassSystem.extend(MyWidget, Widget)

console.log(ClassSystem.getByBaseClass(Widget).length) // Will output 1
console.log(ClassSystem.getByBaseClass(Widget)) // Will output [MyWidget()]
```

Just a very simple version that you could extend as you want.

Comment: I was hoping for a more built-in solution, but this would work just fine.  Thanks!